# Cannot install plyfile in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, ply-file-format

When u=i try to run the command

```
conda install plyfile
```

in windows command prompt

```
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
- plyfile

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?
plyfile: olefile

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with
anaconda search -t conda plyfile
```

I tried to use

```
pip install plyfile
```

and it executed without any error but it still won't show up in Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Anaconda install folder

```
(default) C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

there you should find PIP used by Anaconda, try running

```
pip install plyfile
```

from that location.